# php code within value attribute for html

Tags: php, html, attributes, space

I have a html form with a textbox in which i want to pull the name of the person signed in to automatically be filled in the text box when the page loads. below is the code i am using.

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="createdby" id="createdby" value= <?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?> readonly>
```

the issue is with the php code

```html
   <?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>
```

Because of the space between .' ' . the last name does not show. however when i remove the space  both the first name and the last name show but without any spaces. How do i pull both names from the database and have them separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it needs to look as follows:

```
<...value="<?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use double quotes around your php tags.

Comment: That was a right answer. Don't forget to add the corrected code for the OP and future readers. Code is often more explicit and easier to read than text ;) Explanations are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`implode()` looks better then such concatenation:

```
implode(' ', array($first_name, $last_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert this:

```
<?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>
```

Into this:

```
<?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>
```

Or this if you want to simplify variables concatenation:

```
<?php echo “$first_name $last_name” ?>
```

Use the standard php tags and explicitly echo your values